# Interpreting a voltage requirement given both as a range and as a percentage?

Tags: voltage, documentation

The following table contains the input power specifications for a laser printer:

[image]

([Source](https://www.printertec.com.br/arquivos_download/4000.pdf) page *1-9*)

As you can see, the volts listing is given both as a range, "100-127" and also as a percentage "±10%".  What is the meaning of this?

i.e., does it mean the actual range is 90 - 139.7 VAC? Something else?

Why would they choose a seemingly ambiguous format for this information?

---

Note, I don't think they have just copied this from national standards. e.g., [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity#Standardization)

> "In the United States and Canada, national standards specify that the
>   nominal voltage at the source should be 120 V and allow a range of 114
>   V to 126 V (RMS) (−5% to +5%)."

I'm pretty sure this printer was designed for sale in that market. This doesn't seem to match the range given in the documentation.

Comment: on a side note, I *direly* need to attach a power meter to my printer to see whether I've got an expensive room heater when it's in standby.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell exactly what the author of the datasheet of this err... classic¹ printer meant, but my interpretation:

Any grid voltage between 100 and 127 V is OK, as long as it doesn't fluctuate more than +- 10 %, and has a frequency of either 50 or 60 Hz, with a frequency tolerance of 3%.

---

¹ wow, 22W *standby*... that's somewhere in the 1 to 4 W range for modern laser printers. If you plan to use that printer: do a yearly power usage calculation to make sure you're not effectively paying more in electricity for your old printer than you'd pay for a new one. For example, assuming the thing is in standby 97% of a year, and it uses 20W more than a modern printer, and a price of 30ct/kWh, that's pretty much 50€ you're converting to nothing a year more. Might be worth investing 80€ in a [new](https://www.heise.de/preisvergleich/lexmark-b2236dw-18m0110-a2010510.html?v=k&hloc=at&hloc=de&hloc=uk) laser printer, even if toner is slightly more expensive, especially because printers *really* got faster and better in the last 20 years.

Comment: You're clearly right about the standby losses. Unless you use electric heat most of the year anyway...

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is a consumer product and so the confusion in the power requirement is not totally unexpected.

I may be wrong, but I think they're double booking the variability in the input power specification.  The range specified, 100 - 127 VAC is over which the product is supposed to operate correctly.  I don't think you extend that range by an additional 10% on either end.  If that's what their intent was, they should have just specified the range as 90 - 139.7 VAC, IMO.

Sometimes the percentage after the range is added to allow for uncertainties in the verification process, but 10% seems very generous.

If someone wants to verify the 100 - 127 VAC range by testing, there is going to be some uncertainty in the test equipment and the measurement process.  Does the test AC power supply need to be accurate to 1%, 0.1%, 0.0001%?  So the percentage tacked on to the range helps determine how good the test setup needs to be.

If the +/-10% number is really supposed to mean grid fluctuation, does that apply over a short term or a long term, and what is meant by "short term" and "long term".  And if that's the intent, that should be a separate line in the power requirements section.

Comment: In the first statement were you referring to confusion on the part of the consumer? Or on the author?

Comment: Both.  I think the author could have done a better job at specifying the input power requirements, which would lessen the confusion on the part of the consumer.

Comment: good points, honestly. Thanks!